# Restricting google api key for expo react native

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm currently in the development phase of a react native application using the google cloud API key, the google cloud API allows you to add domain restrictions such as HTTPS, ios, Andriod, etc. How do I add a restriction to only use this API key in my expo localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

1. Find your IP address (whatismyip.com)
2. Add that in the IP restrictions of your API key

That should do it. Be aware that if your external IP changes, you should modify the restriction, in order to whitelist your new IP.